# Is there a verb for unintentionally showing your rear end?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I’m trying to be civil here.  But two friends were sitting on the ground at the park, and their rear ends were very visible to everyone, so I wanted a verb similar to *mooning,* but ***mooning* sounds intentional**.

> Hey, you both are [unintentionally mooning] everyone behind you.
>
> Ugh, the plumber was in the kitchen and [unintentionally showing his rear end] while I was eating.

Comment: Yeah, *plumber's crack* or *plumber's butt* is probably the most idiomatic in the US.  http://www.duluthtrading.com/store/mens/duluth-ingenuity/mens-longtail-t-shirts/features/AD_Plumber.aspx

Answer (score 3):

A *one-word verb* that fits would be **to plumber-butt**.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buttock_cleavage#Lexicon):

> The terms **plumber butt** or **plumber's crack** (Canadian, Australian and
>   American English) and **builder's bum** (British English) refer to the
>   exposure of male buttock cleavage, especially on occasions of careless
>   bending over.

While usually it's "plumber's butt" (noun), a verb *plumber-butt* also exists, [according to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22plumber-butting%22):

> When you put on your pants, is the band of your underwear above the
>   top of your pants or **are you just plumber-butting** all over the place?
>
> If you're bending over to stretch, you should be confident that you
>   **won't be plumber-butting** the cardio wing. (in a gym.)

Evidently plumber-butting is mostly unintentional. It is certainly no mooning.

Regarding your examples:

> "Hey, you both are **plumber-butting** everyone behind you."

The second one is trickier and needs some rephrasing, perhaps:

> "Ugh, the plumber was in the kitchen and, you know, did what the
>   plumbers do: he **plumber-butted** me while I was eating."

Or simply:

> "Ugh, the plumber was in the kitchen, **plumber-butting** me while I
>   was eating."

Comment: *Plumber butt* is so blunt. The German equivalent translates to *plumber’s décolleté.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft 'In France, it is usually referred to as le sourire du plombier, which translates to "the plumber's smile".' - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buttock_cleavage#Lexicon